# Regex expression taking care of unknown words in a sentence

Tags: regex

I'm trying to **figure out a regular expression syntax** that will match the following strings:

- The City has not fully complied with its obligations under the Prior Undertaking
- The School District has not fully complied with its obligations under the Prior Undertaking
- The District has not fully complied with its obligations under the Prior Undertaking

So far, I have the following:
`The (?!.*(no|never|not)).{0,50}? has not fully complied with its obligations under the Prior Undertaking`

But, it is not working on https://regex101.com. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what do you want to accomplish with `(?!.*(no|never|not)).{0,50}?` ? Currently there is not match because this lookahead `(?!.*(no|never|not))` fails in all sentences. Can you update the question with what it should not match?

Comment: Hi. I was playing around on regex101.com. ```the (?!.*(no|never|not)).{0,50} may``` matched with ```the damn may n```. So, I thought it could be useful. I'm not sure, sorry.

Comment: Oh, I think I got this. ```The (?!.*(yummy|tummy)).{0,50} has not fully complied``` is working.

Comment: Are you looking for this? `The (?:(?!no|never|not).){0,50}? has not fully complied with its obligations under the Prior Undertaking` https://regex101.com/r/okAjXh/1

Comment: What if `yummy` or `tummy` occur farther than fifty chars? Maybe you need `The (?!.{0,45}(yummy|tummy)).{0,50} has not fully complied`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current pattern does not match any of the example strings, because this part `The (?!.*(no|never|not))` asserts from that position that either `no` `never` and `not` should not occur to the right.

But for all 3 example strings, one of the words is present.

What you might do is write the pattern using a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat#:%7E:text=Tempered%20greedy%20token%20is%20resource,increase%20tempered%20greedy%20token%20performance) approach:

```
The (?:(?!no|never|not).){0,50}? has not fully complied with its obligations under the Prior Undertaking
```

This part `(?:(?!no|never|not).){0,50}?` now repeat 0-50 times as least as possible matching a single character asserting what is not directly to the right is either of the listed words.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/okAjXh/1)